# play routes issue for static resource with others

Tags: playframework

I'm having the problem that play cannot identify the following routes `/assets` and `/assets/id` and returns `{"error":{"code":404,"message":"The resource you requested could not be found","errors":["Resource not found by Assets controller"]}}` If I remove `/assets/*file` then it works for `/assets` and `/assets/id`. any ideas what I did wrong?

```
# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file                 controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
GET     /assets/                      mypackage.AssetController.getData(name: Option[String])
GET     /assets/:id                   mypackage.AssetController.getDataId(id: Long)
```

Answer (score 0):

The routing file is about order and pattern (first in file highest priority).

So in your routing everything is matched by `/assets/*file`.

`GET /assets/:id` is also not static as you may consider another route.

Here an example:

```
GET     /images/:id                   mypackage.AssetController.getDataId(id: Long)
GET     /assets/*file                       controllers.Assets.at(file)
```

Or if you want to keep `/assets/:id`

```
GET     /assets/:id                   mypackage.AssetController.getDataId(id: Long)
GET     /assets/*file                       controllers.Assets.at(file)
```

Here you must be aware that only something like `/assets/images/img.png` will be matched by the second route. (with only one slash, e.g. `/assets/img.png` will be matched by the first route.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I do not know your intension on having 3 `/assets` related routes. Two things here:

1. The one liner route definition (with the route of `/assets/*file`) is required to get your scripts and style sheets files (from `/public`) within your views templates. That is all you need! So why do you want to have two other routes? What other things you want to add your assets folder?
2. The order of the routes are important, the order is from top to bottom until one that matches. For example, if I have:

   ```
   GET /blog/:name                     controllers.Blog.get(name: String) 
   GET /blog/iwillNeverGetPickedUp     controllers.Blog.cantBeUsed
   ```

the second route is never get picked up; because the first route is getting matched first. That is, in fact the scenario you created with your routes. which is between your `assets/:id` and `assets/*file` routes.